# insertion sort using linked list and pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I need to sort linked list using insertion sort. 
The elements looks like this 
[ 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 ]

The result of sorting should look like 
[ 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 ]

The problem is that my result looks like this
[ 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 ]

I'm not sure why...I feel like it should work...but maybe other eyes will spot the problem.

Main:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

IntElement *ints[N_ELEMENTS];
for (int i = 0; i < N_ELEMENTS; i++) {
    ints[i] = new IntElement (i%4);
}
SortedList slist;
for (int i = 0; i < N_ELEMENTS; i++) {
    slist.addElement (ints[i]);
}
slist.print();
printf ("last = %s\n", slist.get (slist.size ()-1)->toString ());`
```

sort function in .cpp File

```
void SortedList::addElement(IElement * element)
{
entryPtr n = new entry;
n->next = NULL;
n->me = element;
curr = head;

if (curr == NULL) {
    //Executes when linked list is empty
    head = n;
    return;
}

if (n->me < curr->me)
{
    //Executes if given data is less than data in first node of linked list
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
    return;
}
else 
{
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (n->me>curr->me)
        {
            //Traverse to location we want to insert the node + 1 node
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert the node
            prev->next = n;
            n->next = curr;
            return;
        }
    }
    //Insert node at last
    prev->next = n;

}
```

}

.h File

```
class SortedList {

protected:

typedef struct entry {                                      // stores an element and a pointer to the next element in the list
    IElement *me;
    entry *next;
}*entryPtr;

entryPtr head;
entryPtr curr;
entryPtr prev;
entryPtr temp;

public:

SortedList();
 ~SortedList() {};

void addElement(IElement *element);           // adds element to the list and returns position, -1 if not added
IElement *get(int position);                  // returns element at given position
int size();                                   // returns the number of elements in the list
void print(FILE *file = stdout);             // prints all elements
};
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing values pointed to by the pointers in statements like this

```
if (n->me < curr->me)
```

you are comparing pointers themselves.

You should rewrite the condition like

```
if ( *n->me < *curr->me )
```